# Update applications with another users AppleID - possible bug?

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore, software-update

The situations is this.

1. *I* installed *all* the the relevant apps from the App Store on my MacBook Pro using *my* AppleID and the apps could be updated for a long time using *my* AppleID.
2. Some time ago I created a user account on my machine for my daughter and for unrelated reasons made it an admin account.
3. Some apps installed as per 1. now require my daughters AppleID to update.

From reading lots of answers on this site it seems that apps installed by other users must be uninstalled/reinstalled to work resolve this issue. As this is not the case for me, does anyone know what might be causing this change of AppleIDs and if it is possible to revert back? As far as I can see this must be a bug.

Have anyone experienced this and is there a way to resolve this other than the uninstall/reinstall solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on High Sierra or before, you can navigate to the app in the Applications folder, then right click the app and choose Show Package Contents. From the folder that pops up, expand the _MASReceipt folder and delete the receipt file. The app will now update properly.

If you're on Mojave you have to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: To my understanding, removing an app's _MASReceipt will prevent it from updating at all, on any version of macOS. Can you please provide a source to back up your answer?

Comment: I finally had to reinstall the apps. (Returning to properly close my question)